# Clojure macro evaluation of strings

Tags: clojure

I am trying to create a clojure macro that converts an entered symbol to a string. However, when I do this:

```
(defmacro convert-to-string [something]
  `(call-converted "~something")
  )

(macroexpand '(convert-to-string convert-this))
```

: I get :

```
(call-converted "~something")
```

: instead of :

```
(call-converted "~convert-this")
```

: does anyone show me how I could do this?

Comment: Are you sure this needs to be a macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider using keywords (or quoted symbols) and a function, rather than a macro:

```
(defn convert-to-string [x] (call-converted (name x)))
(convert-to-string :foo)
(convert-to-string 'foo)
```

If you really want a macro:

```
(defmacro convert-to-string [x] `(call-converted ~(name x)))
(macroexpand-1 '(convert-to-string foo))
=> (user/call-converted "foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in no way an expert on macros, but would this solve your problem:

```
(defmacro to-str [expr] (str expr))
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong as this gives an error when I run it with: (defmacro to-str [expr] (str expr))

(macroexpand '(to-str something)) as this returns something (without the quotes) instead of "something" (with quotes)